# Objective-C fallback language iOS

Tags: ios, localization

In an app I am working on we are using

```
#define ZZAPPLocalizedString(key, comment) NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, @"ZZZ",  comment)
```

for translations. How do I make this so that it will fallback to the english file if the translation is not available in the current language?

Comment: It should already be handled by iOS. If English is your base development language, then English.lproj files are loaded by default if there is not anything else.

Comment: Doesn't happen, i get the key instead.. Maybe the problem is that the localisation file for that language exists but it doesn't have the key.. I want it to show english in this case as well

Comment: Oh yeah of course, the key must be present in the English file :) Otherwise it just shows the key indeed.

Comment: The key is present in the english file.. it's not present in the other files (eg french file) so if the iphone is set to french all the text that is in french appears but the rest shows the key

Comment: Yeah and that's the normal behavior. So you want to get the English translation whenever the key is not available, for example, in the French translation ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the behaviour I'm looking for

Comment: You have two options : either mess with preferred languages at runtime, which isn't ideal in order to detect if a key is missing in target language, or use some tool that would fill missing keys with their English translations in other languages strings files.